# How to check a php array, that contain the same value as other array

Tags: php, arrays

i have two array which is `$a` and `$b`, where the value of the array is same but the index of elements is different.

```
$a 
Array ( [0] => there is bald spot on the inside or outside of tyre [1] => uneven tyre wear )
```

```
$b
Array ( [0] => uneven tyre wear [1] => there is bald spot on the inside or outside of tyre )
```

but when i compare by using `$a == $b` , it return `false` even when the elements inside the array, is same (just the position of elements is different.)

solutions given before is

```
$a = Array ( 
    0 => 'there is bald spot on the inside or outside of tyre',
    1 => 'uneven tyre wear'

);

$b = Array ( 
       0 => 'uneven tyre wear', 
       1 => 'there is bald spot on the inside or outside of tyre' 
    );

if(count(array_diff($a,$b)) == 0){
    echo "both array are identical";    

}
```

but if i remove an elements from $a

```
$a = Array ( 
    0 => 'there is bald spot on the inside or outside of tyre'
    //1 => 'uneven tyre wear'

);
```

it still shows the identical if using the solution above.

Comment: use `array_diff()` to check that

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie I just post [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp) to this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
if(count(array_diff($a,$b)) == 0){
    echo "both array are identical";    

}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/vEUiQ

***Note:-*** in case if both array size differs (one have more elements and other have less elements), then you have to put bigger array at first postion while using `array_diff()`

Check this output:- https://3v4l.org/9lNae

Answer (score 0):

use array_diff()

```
<?php
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2)
print_r($result);
?>
```